# Error 2753 feature tree..How do I avoid?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Is there a way I can avoid this error 2753 ?? I want to de select a few features during installation time and if i de select i get this error. How do i avoid that and still be able to select the features I WANT:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that you have a custom action that's referencing a file installed by a feature.  You need to give the custom action a condition that limits it's invocation to when that component file is being installed.  Otherwise you'll get an error when the custom action executes because the file isn't available.

Comment: So , here are my custom actions , could you just help me with the conditions. I am really bad at that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" FileKey="VcredistEXE" 
ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="StartAppOnExit" Before="InstallFinalize">!SOMECOMPONENTID=3</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit1" FileKey="InterUMIEXE" 
 ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait"  Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit1" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>

 <CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit2" FileKey="Python" 
ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="StartAppOnExit2"  Before="InstallFinalize"  />
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
 <WriteEnvironmentStrings>EnableEV=1</WriteEnvironmentStrings>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx See: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_custom.htm

Comment: Basically you want to write a condition like $COMPONENTID=3 where COMPONENTID is the Id of the component for a given FileKey.   This basically means "Component (file) is being installed".

Comment: I edited the first Custom element in your sample to show you what it looks like.